# Don't publish Group post on members wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an application that posts, using the graph api, on user's selected groups/pages/wall.

What's happening is that if one member belongs to more than one of the groups the user selected to post to, those posts are displayed more than once in the member's wall. I mean, the same post information but each one on the corresponding group.

Is there a way to tell Facebook api not to show those post on the member's wall?
How could I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but can't you just store the IDs of the groups you've already posted to, and not post multiple times to the same group?

You could also check the group's `feed` connection before posting to see if there's already an equivalent post

Comment: Thanks. I'm not posting multiple times to the same group. I do one post per group but if someone belongs to more than one of those groups they'll see the message duplicated in their wall. Also if I don't post to one of the groups some people may not get the message.